# Qual o motivo do erro já que o JQuery esta sendo importado

Tags: jquery, angular, materialize

Estou utilizando o Materialize junto com Angular, porém o dropdown do menu não está funcionando.

Com o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dropdown is not a function
>   at funcoes.js:6

O arquivo funcoes.js tem a seguinte linha de código apenas:

```
$(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown()
```

Comment: o Arquivo funcoes.js é chamado após a inclusão da biblioteca jQuery? Edite sua pergunta para exibir como você inclui o jquery e a fonte script de funções.

Comment: Sim, dentro do body
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/funcoes.js"> </script>

Comment: Estou utilizando o materialize

Comment: e onde você importa ele?

Answer (score 0):

Reveja se todas as bibliotecas necessárias foram importadas e se estão na ordem correta.

- jQuery
- Materialize.js
- Materialize.css

Segue abaixo um exemplo funcionando:

```js
$(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<a class='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#' data-target='dropdown1'>Importe tods as bibliotecas \/</a>

<ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
  <li><a href="#!">jQuery</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">materialize.js</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">materialize.css</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

no angular-cli.json também deve ser importado

```
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.js",
    "../node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.js"
  ],
```

e definir o $ no app.module.ts

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```